# Get Page.Master Instance without Cast

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I am trying to get a master's page instance without cast.

Something like this but without cast

```
var masterPage = (MasterPageName)Page.Master;
        if (masterPage != null) {
            masterPage.Foo = false;
        }
```

Is there any workaround for this?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2639449/102112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make MasterPageName to implement an interface IFoo which has the boolean Foo defined, so in your code above you could check if Page.Master is IFoo and you do not need any cast.

Comment: thanks a lot. I did this and it worked but again with cast. It doesn't annoying me, but if you have a better idea, please share it with me :). this is what I've done var masterPage = (IMasterPage)Page.Master;

Comment: IMasterPage m = Page.Master as IMasterPage;
  if( m != null ) m.Foo = true;